# Pattern match 301, retaining one querystring parameter

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-301

Been scratching my head over this one. I have a URL format I need to redirect and only need one part of the querystring. Example URL:

> tiles?shape=&colour=&finish=&material=&price=&o=60&tile=50-double-roman-antique-red-03-granular

All I need from this is the value of the tile parameter (50-double-roman-antique-red-03-granular) so I can then redirect it to:

> tiles/detail/50-double-roman-antique-red-03-granular

Any suggestions for a rewrite rule?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This works on my box. We're including the `?` after the rewrite string to prevent the behavior or `QSA` or query string append which is the default behavior if no query string is passed. If you forget the `?` then it creates a loop.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} tile=([^&]+)&?.*$
RewriteRule (.*) /tiles/detail/%1? [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

This off-topic answer gave me what I was looking for:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} &tile=([0-9a-zA-Z-]+)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !tiles/detail
RewriteRule tiles /tiles/detail/%1? [R=301]
```